# Forking DAC output

Tags: operational-amplifier, dac, mixer

I am designing circuit based on stereo [UDA1334BTS](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/UDA1334BTS.pdf). The audio output should go to two inputs - 3.5 mm jack line out, and to internal appliance's mixer/amplifier.

The issues here are:

1. I have no idea what device may be plugged into the jack connector, it may have any impedance;
2. internal appliance's mixer is built on simple resistor network, thus its impedance is just several kOhm which may lead to cross-talk and affect jack output.

My initial idea is to have voltage followers (probably with some filtering circuitry) for each channel for each output destination, it will require 4 op-amps (2 x 2).

Another issue is that DAC is 3.3 V, outputs amplitude in range ~ 0.3-3.0 V, and I guess to get decent op-amp output I should not power op-amps from 3.3 V, and will need other power rail (e.g. 5 V, or ±12 V), these voltages are not available close to the DAC chip and output connectors.

Can you recommend any better design for my issue?

Comment: You can operate your opamp with a virtual ground at half of the opamp power supply.  If you have a 3.3V supply and a rail to rail opamp that will run on 3.3V, then you could use a virtual ground of 1.65V.

Comment: Just keep in mind that if you go that route (single-supply opamp with a virtual ground) you need to AC couple the output with a big capacitor. Consumer peak-to-peak line level is 0.9V full-swing, so your opamp with a swing of 3.0-0.3 = 2.7V can easily handle that.

Comment: In previous revision of the board I used AD8510, very satisfied with it, was looking if I can use AD8512 (two in MSOP package), but their starting supply voltage is ±4.5 V (thus 9 V) :(